# How to use module.exports in browser? (not node js)

Tags: javascript, module, commonjs

I am aware of the use of module.exports on node js.
My question is: Is there a way to export and require modules in the common js module format in a non-node.js environment?

In the browser side, I checked the example code for the code that define and require for AMD. However, the test code for module.exports and require fails.

test.html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>test</h2>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
//AMD
require(["js/a"], function(a) {
  const result = a.add(1, 2);
  console.log('result: ', result);
});

//CommonJS
var a = require('js/a');
const result = a.add(1,2);
console.log('result: ', result);
```

a.js

```
//AMD
define(function() {
  return {
    add(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    subtract(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }
  };
});

//CommonJS
module.exports = function(a,b){
  return {
    add : function(){
      return a+b;
    }
  }
};
```

how can i use commonjs's module format ? (module.exports and require)

Comment: You can look in to using something like http://browserify.org/ or https://webpack.js.org/